# Float left divs going to next line

Tags: html, css

I have something similar to below:

```
<div style="float:left;margin-left:5px;">Test</div>
```

The issue is that I need to have this div repeat multiple times.  If it repeats to many times, instead of forcing you to scroll right to see the rest of it (like I want it to), it instead goes down to the next line.

Example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ruh7z/1/

Any help with this would be great, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That behavior is exactly what floating is supposed to do.  If you use `table-cell` for your `display` style, that may give you more of what you're expecting.  Note that you'll have to use padding instead of margins if you use `table-cell`.

```
.container div
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jB5M3/1/) of this in use.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that was part of float's functioning. That is a very elegant solution ^^.

Comment: It should be noted that ' display: table-cell; ' is not supported pre Internet Explorer 8. All other browsers support it. +1'd

Answer (score 0):

put the div's in a "fixed width" container div and prevent overflow.  then have buttons or whatever at each end of the container div to "slide" the child divs left or right.